# io.js не запускается из cmd в windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js

Суть ситуации такова: установлен io.js, установлен node.js 6.10.0 , набирая в командной строке *iojs server.js* (команду запуска скрипта), получаем:

> "iojs" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой
>   программой или пакетным файлом.

Подскажите что не так, может кто с таким сталкивался, как запустить скрипт через io.js?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Небось, в переменных среды (в смысле "окружения", environment) путь до файла не прописан: Панель управления -> Система -> Дополнительные параметры -> Переменные среды и PATH. (предполагаю, что в Windows 10 в этой части - всё так же) Стандартное же сообщение - Windows не знает путь до екзешника программы.

А вообще, у меня как бы встречный вопрос - а зачем? Насколько известно, с версии Node 4.0.0 io.js в неё интегрирована. Команда node script.js должна бы иметь тот же самый эффект.

Comment: Да, _node script.js имеет тот же эффект_ в этом случае незачем. Спасибо!